# Excel VBA "compile error expected end of statement" (Parenthesis issue)

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

I tried below code in excel vba and always getting error

> excel vba compile error expected end of statement

```
Range("O1").Value = "=MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,FIND(")",A1)-FIND("(",A1)-1)"
```

And when I try to solve it with Double quote below

```
Range("O1").Value = "=MID(A1,FIND(""("",A1)+1,FIND("")"",A1)-FIND(""("",A1)-1)"
```

Then the formula that appear in cell "O1" is

```
=MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,FIND(")",A1)-FIND("(",A1)-1)
```

And formula doesn't work because it find "(" instead of just find only (

Comment: "And formula doesn't work because it find "(" instead of just find only ("... check again. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeV37.png

Comment: Hah !!! It is work now. Just because i define cell "O1" to Text, feel like an idiot. THANK YOU.